# debug.activeDebugSession API returns undefined on vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I have an issue when trying to play with the `debug api` of `vscode`. This is the code I'm using:

```
const vscode = require('vscode');

function activate(context) {

    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "helloworld" is now active!');

    let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', function () {

        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World!'); // This works

        const session = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession;
        console.log(session); // returns undefined

        // I have tried this one, and no text is shown
        vscode.debug.activeDebugConsole.append("Hello from Debug Console");

        if (session) {
            session.customRequest("evaluate", {
                "expression": "Math.sqrt(10)"
            }).then(reply => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`result: ${reply.result}`);
            }, error => {
                vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`error: ${error.message}`);
            });
        }
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}
exports.activate = activate;

function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
}
```

To try this I have made the following steps:

- created simple `"Hello World"` extension with yeoman.
- replaced the `extension.js` with the code from above.
- pressed **F5** to launch (and debug) extension.
- in new window opened a simple node.js program.
- pressed **F5** to debug simple program.
- pressed **F1** and typed "Hello" and ran the "Hello World" extension.

But `const session = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession;` returns `undefined`.

Also `vscode.debug.activeDebugConsole.append("Hello from Debug Console");` does not shows anything.

I know that **if there is no active debug session**, the code from above will not work properly. So:

Do I correctly have an active debug session? What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue, following these steps:

- create a simple `"Hello World"` extension with yeoman.
- replace the `extension.js` with the code from above.
- press **F5** to launch (and debug) extension.
- in new window opened, click on **File Menu**, then click on **Open Folder**, and select a folder where is a simple **node.js program** or a **vscode workplace** (**this is very important**).
- Set a breakpoint in some line (**also important to a appreciate the behaviour of the test**).
- press **F5** to debug simple program (**this is how to open an active debug session**).
- press **F1** and type "Hello" and ran the "Hello World" extension.
- Appreciate the results !!!

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion: you have to subscribe to `vscode.debug.onDidStartDebugSession` and `vscode.debug.onDidTerminateDebugSession` to keep track of when a session *starts/ends* or use `onDidChangeActiveDebugSession` when *changing*. At that point, you can know that a session is active, and your code should run.

Comment: Your suggestions did not solved my problem, but they aimed my head at new research. Thanks for that ! (Upvoted it)